# django 1.11 makemigration error with custom range field

Tags: python, django, validation, django-migrations

at djangosnippets I found a example for a IntegerRangeField (https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3016/)

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db import models


class IntegerRangeField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        validators = []
        if isinstance(max_value, int):
            validators.append(MaxValueValidator(max_value))
        if isinstance(min_value, int):
            validators.append(MinValueValidator(min_value))
        models.IntegerField.__init__(
            self,
            verbose_name,
            name,
            validators=validators,
            **kwargs
        )

def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 'max_value':self.max_value}
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(IntegerRangeField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

My model:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
    .....
    automatic_logout_value = IntegerRangeField (min_value=5, max_value=1440, 
                               blank=True, null=True, default=30)
```

After starting "python manage.py makemigrations" I get the error:

```
c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py line 437, in from_model 
e,
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field automatic_logout_value on myApp.myModel:
__init__ () got multiple values for keyword 'validators'
```

Any idea whats wrong with the code?
Thanks!

Comment: indent your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class IntegerRangeField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        models.IntegerField.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(max_value, int):
            self.validators.append(MaxValueValidator(max_value))
        if isinstance(min_value, int):
            self.validators.append(MinValueValidator(min_value))
```

can you try this code, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to pop `validators` from `kwargs`. By default it is a tuple, so you need to convert it to a list so that you can append items.

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, **kwargs):
    self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
    validators = list(kwargs.pop('validators'))
    ...
```